# allow gridlookupedit control to search only after typing two characters

Tags: vb.net

I am using third party tool "gridlookupedit" of DevXpress in my application. I have loaded the gridlookupedit control on the key Down event of it. Now if i type a character "A" the dropdown gets loaded with all values starting with "A". Now a step ahead i want to load the GridLookUpEdit only after two characters.
for rg: the control must load values only when user types any two characters. If user types "A" it should not load. if user types "Ab" then the control should be loaded by the values starting with "Ab".
how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

On your Key Down event I guess you've got some code that populates gridlookupedit? If so just put a if around your code to only update if the length is grater than 1

```
If gridlookupedit.Length > 1 Then

' Update List

End If
```